# Typing Latex symbol

Tags: math-mode, fonts, math-fonts

I am unable to write a particular font of `V` in LaTeX (attached below). If some knows please let me know. Would be great help.

[image]

Comment: This looks like a `\mathscr{V}` from the `mathrsfs` package.

Comment: Try `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\begin{document}
\[p\mathscr{V}=MRT\]
\end{document}`.

Comment: I believe @Lazysquirrel has already answered, but if you wish to look at several Latex math script styles there is this useful page: [Latex script styles for math](http://www.peteryu.ca/tutorials/publishing/latex_math_script_styles)

Answer (score 7):

I have choosen another option, looking the https://ctan.mirror.garr.it/mirrors/ctan/macros/latex/contrib/mathalpha/doc/mathalpha-doc.pdf (`mathalfa=mathalpha`) package. You can see to pag. 5, 6 and 7 that there are many option for the *calligraphic upright characters*. For my humble opinion you can choose or `scr=boondox` or `scr=boondoxupr` that it is very closer with the image. The font of default of your image is times new roman and hence.....

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}
\usepackage[scr=boondox]{mathalfa}

\begin{document}
$p$ it is the pressure, and if $\mathscr{V}$ is the volume we have:
\begin{equation}
    p\mathscr{V}=MRT
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Edit after the comment of the user @Lazy squirrel**: I have deleted the blank space between `M` and `R` using `\!` (negative space).

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}
\usepackage[scr=boondox]{mathalfa}

\begin{document}
$p$ it is the pressure, and if $\mathscr{V}$ is the volume we have:
\begin{equation}
    p\mathscr{V}=M{\!}RT
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Why is the space between `R` and `T` so much smaller than between `M` and `R`?

Comment: @Lazysquirrel I really don't know. :-) I try to make an investigation before going to sleep :-). Maybe because I'm compiling with Papeeria.

Comment: I posted a question, it does not seem to be specific to your choice of fonts.