# A little blank space using an MWE with newtxtext, newtxmath and mathalfa

Tags: fonts, spacing, packages, newtxmath, newtx

Giving an answer for this question [Typing Latex symbol](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/573900/typing-latex-symbol) the user @Lazy squirrel have noticed that there is a blank spacing between the character `M` and `R`. Why? What is the reason?

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}
\usepackage[scr=boondox]{mathalfa}

\begin{document}
$p$ it is the pressure, and if $\mathscr{V}$ is the volume we have:
\begin{equation}
    p\mathscr{V}=MRT
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The italic correction for the M is 0.972pt. A choice of the font designer, possibly excessive. The T has 1.668pt, but the R only 0.246pt.

Comment: To be clear, I am complaining about the too small space between `R` and `T`, which was more generous in older installations.

Comment: @egreg with cm one see similar values.

Comment: @egreg What is the solution? :-) I use for my book newtxtext :-(.

Comment: @Lazysquirrel I don't know if I should remove my question. I am available to remove it with the consent of the users.

Comment: Is it appropriate to write to Michael Sharpe (newtx manteiner) or is it a general problem?

Comment: Well, I do not know. There seem to be a bunch of users who are all-too eager to agree that (i) nothing changed from the past and (ii) the spacing is fine. I disagree with both assertions. Maybe I am the only one. Maybe not. I just happen to find it suspicious how quickly they want to close the questions or make it invisible for general users by other means. One could almost get the impression that there is something that needs to be hidden.

Comment: @Lazysquirrel I respect everyone and with all sincerity I did not understand the meaning of your last part. With me there is no problem whatsoever. You are also a very good user. My greetings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that `newtxmath` follows rather strictly the Computer Modern model in this respect.

If I ask `\showoutput`, I get

```
.....\OML/cmm/m/it/12 M
.....\kern1.25348
.....\OML/cmm/m/it/12 R
.....\kern0.09879
.....\OML/cmm/m/it/12 T
.....\kern1.63193
```

with Computer Modern and

```
.....\OML/ntxmi/m/it/12 M
.....\kern0.972
.....\OML/ntxmi/m/it/12 R
.....\kern0.246
.....\OML/ntxmi/m/it/12 T
.....\kern1.668
```

with `newtxmath`. The kerns refer to the italic correction that's always added after characters in the math letter font.

The italic correction for the R has been varying through the years in `newtxmath`: it used to be 0.029 from 2012 to 2015; it jumped to 0.0385 between 2016 and 2018, to be shrunk to 0.0205 in 2019 (these values have to by multiplied by the font size, so this corresponds to a kern of 0.246pt at 12pt size).

With 0.0385 one would get a kern of 0.462pt and the output would be

[image]

to be compared with the current output

[image]

Kerning a font is a very difficult task; looking at the output at small resolution is not the best way to judge.

Comment: Thank you very much "immensamente".....