# Problem with new TeXLive installation: spacing in math mode

Tags: spacing

I was thinking I was seeing ghosts but am getting more and more confident that I do not. Consider the MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\[pV=\nu RT\;,\]
\end{document}
```

which produces

[image]

whereas in older documents it looked like

[image]

What is bothering me is the distance between `R` and `T`.

Note that this does not seem to depend on the font, as you may object because the samples are slightly different, but e.g. [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/573904) shows the same problem. I also tried out other fonts and so on, and loading `microtype` and `mathpazo` appears to help a tiny bit, yet I am very confident that the output of the example on the top looked way better when compiled a year ago, say, i.e. with TeXLive 2019. What amI doing wrong? Or is this due to the kernel change?

Comment: I see no reason for any change here, are you using pdftex or luatex or ...

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I am using `pdflatex`. I also used `pdflatex` to generate the older file where the spacing was better.

Comment: the space between R and T depends entirely on the font, your images are clearly different fonts so don't really show any problem.

Comment: I tried your example with various tex live versions and see not change in the spacing over the years.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Well, yes, but I cannot compile on an older installation. All I know is that I would have noticed if in earlier versions `R` and `T` were that close to each other. (Trying to compile the other document on the new installation will also not be too useful because its preamble is enormous, and this is no longer an MWE. All I can say is that I am pretty positive to have noted that `R` and `T` are so close on an older installation.)

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Well, then it must be due to something that you did not unupdate.

Comment: [tl2020](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TGqhV.png)   [tl2019](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fCZjI.png) [tl2016](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aG8vV.png)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Well, I see what you are saying but I can only repeat that I cannot recall having seen `R` and `T` that close at any point in time.

Comment: I used local installations there but you can test yourself eg at overleaf you can use texlive 2014 - 2020

Comment: @Lazysquirrel this spacing has not changed since the computer modern fonts were introduced in the 1980s.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Well, what can I say? Older notes do have a different spacing, if I look at the internet, the spacing in the older online notes looks different, but you will always be able to object that I am not able to prove that they were generated with something that resembles the above. All I can say is that I am sure I would have noted that the spacing is too tight in the old days.

Comment: @Lazysquirrel no, I know what I'm doing when I test. But I'm quite sure that you don't tell the whole story, the fonts have changed in your screenshots, and that wouldn't have happened in your small example.

Comment: No sorry you are mistaken, I have voted to close the question for lack of clarity. If you can provide an example where spacing has changed, then of course it can be re-opened.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer As I wrote in the question the preamble of the older screen shot has a different preamble. You willl maintain that the author of  [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/573917) and I are seeing ghosts, and I will maintain that you missed something when you tried to prove us wrong. I will be hard to converge here. Maybe something that we could agree on: do you agree that the spacing in the very first example is a bit unfortunate?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle That's totally fine with me. Just one thing: do you think that the spacing in the very top example is good?

Comment: it's fine but I have been using tex since before the cm fonts were introduced so maybe I'm just used to it and can't give an objective good or bad review.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Well, it is possible that my recollection of a better spacing is also from ancient times. I just firmly believe that I have seen better automatic spacing, but this could be over 20 years back, when I last typed the formula in with a preamble that comes close to what I have above.

Comment: no. 20 years ago you would almost certainly have been using computer modern and had identical spacing.  the almost modern fonts may have had different spacing but they were only in use for a year or two, at the very start of the tex era.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle All I can say is that I was shocked when I saw the output of `\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\[pV=MRT\;,\]
\end{document}` when compiled with `pdflatex` under TeXLive2020, and I can assure you that I hardly saw anything as shocking as this in a long while.

Comment: in the other posting newtxmath is used, that is a quite different font (and its spacing has changed over the years, as egreg wrote in his answer).

Comment: @UlrikeFischer OK, well the problem is really that, at least from my perspective, the output of `\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\[pV=MRT\]
\end{document}` is bad. We may disagree whether it was better some time back, but perhaps we agree that there is considerable room for improvement?

Comment: it just means you haven't typeset a computer modern RT for a while. inter letter kerns are always a judgement, it's fine to disagree with the font author, but that's not really the subject of the question as written. The computer modern metrics will not change.

Comment: @Lazysquirrel Running `$$pV=\nu RT$$\bye` with `tex` gives the exact same same output, so that is Knuth's design only. The TeX tuneup is next year. Maybe there's time to write to Knuth and tell him you disagree with his spacing

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik I want to wait and see if there are others who agree with me. I find it a bit suspicious how eager everyone seems to be to tell me that the spacing is OK, or that it was always like that. While I am not able to prove that it was different in the past, I firmly believe so, and certainly maintain that the spacing of `\documentclass{article} \begin{document} \[pV=MRT\] \end{document}` has tremendous room for improvement. The second example was only typeset a few years ago, admittedly with other fonts, but I have never seen something as bad as the above.

Comment: the computer modern fonts are famously frozen with Knuth's wish that a document produced in 1985 should produce the same output in 2085, so the spacing has definitely not changed, and even if you consider it bad, it definitely won't change. Your example with the (probably) tx fonts is different, the metrics for that set have evolved over time.

Comment: I made a little exercise and looked the names of those up who have such a strong and clear opinion, who seem to mutually upvote their comments and appear to close the question. **Everyone** is a member of the [LaTeX 3 team](https://www.latex-project.org/about/team/)!!!! Come on guys, please let other opinions be heard! Do not try to to just kill this post because it may hint at a kernel update gone wrong! Be a little bit fair, please, and let *others* decide.

Comment: *Disclaimer: I'm no member of the LaTeX3 team.* Produced with TL: [2018](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JO07o.png), [2019](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OMCNH.png), [2020](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tDTmU.png). I could reproduce what @DavidCarlisle showed and explained (no change in kerning between the last 3 TeX Live versions, the ones I have locally installed). This seems to have *nothing* to do with a kernel update. It might be a good idea to "be a little bit fair" and realise that your memory has tricked you in this case.

Comment: @Lazysquirrel it is trivial for you to check that this is completely unrelated to any changes in latex. You can get identical spacing with plain tex. The fact that the font metrics for computer modern have not changed since they were introduced last century is not a matter of debate it is simply a fact.

Comment: The LaTeX team doesn't maintain the fonts, and as Phelype showed (and you could test that easily yoursefl) they look the same in plain tex

Comment: I *never* claimed that someone changed the fonts! It is just that everyone is telling me that the only way the spacing can change is to change the fonts, which is obviously not the case. It also depends on how paragraphs break and so on. While paragraph breaking isn't important here, I'd urge you to resist the temptation to just say "this must come from the fonts, we did not change fonts, so you are wrong". As I said, I saw the better spacing several years back, and just compiling something on an older installation but an otherwise up-to-date computer doesn't really prove anything.

Comment: Same spacing in an old PDF I got in 2009; the file itself has been produced between 2002 and 2004. While I'm not entirely happy about some recent kernel changes, none of them could have affected spacing; that simply isn't how TeX works.